# Creating summation series functions in Matlab with variables for optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization, machine-learning

I have a dataset with 1125 rows and 64 columns. Where first 554 rows belong to one class and the remaining rows belong to the other class. The objective function

[image: objective function]

is to be minimized in terms of R_1 and R_2 where both are are row vectors(1 x 64). x_i and x_l are the rows from the data matrix. I am trying to minimize this objective function using the optimization toolbox, but I am struggling to get the objective function in the desired form and running into errors. This is how I have coded so far

```
data = xlsread('data.xlsx');
dat1 = data(1:554,:);
dat2 = data(555:1125,:);
f1 = @(x) 0;
f2 = @(x) 0;
%% for digits labeled 0
for i = 1:554
    f1 = @(x) f1 + (dat1(i,:) - x(1)).^2;
end
%% for digits labeled 1
for j = 1:571
    f2 = @(x) f2 + (dat2(j,:) - x(2)).^2;
end
%% final objective function
f = @(x) 1/554*f1 + 1/571*f2;
%%
x = fminunc(f);
```

Please guide me on how to correctly form this type of objective function in Matlab

Comment: Please, do not put code (which is text) as an image. This seems obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your code makes sense. A few issues

- `f1 = @(x) 0;` and `f2 = @(x) 0` define anonymous functions which always return zero. What is the purpose of this?
- Every further definition of `f1`,`f2`,`f` is attempting to do arithmetic operations on an anonymous function. It's not clear what you expect this to accomplish.
- `x = fminunc(f);` is missing an argument, it needs an initial guess as well. This isn't just to initialize the algorithm but also so that `fminunc` knows the dimensions that the input to `f` should have.

For your case `f` should be defined so half the values passed to it refer to `R1` and the other half refer to `R2`. For example define

```
l2_sq = @(x) sum(x.^2,2);  % return norm(x,2)^2 for each row of x
f1 = @(R1) sum(l2_sq(bsxfun(@minus, dat1, R1)));
f2 = @(R2) sum(l2_sq(bsxfun(@minus, dat2, R2)));
f3 = @(R1,R2) -10 * norm(R1-R2,1);
f = @(R) f1(R(1:64)) + f2(R(65:128)) + f3(R(1:64), R(65:128));
```

Since the combined `R` vector has 128 elements, we need to generate an initial guess that contains 128 elements. In this case we could just use random Gaussian noise

```
R0 = randn(1,128);
```

Finally, call `fminunc` as

```
Rhat = fminunc(f, R0);
R1 = Rhat(1:64);
R2 = Rhat(65:128);
```

where `R1` and `R2` are the optimal values.

**Note** In MATLAB 2016b and newer, implicit expansion allows you to replace `bsxfun(@minus, dat1, R1)` with the more efficient `dat1 - R1`. Similarly for `bsxfun(@minus, dat2, R2)`.